# How to use select query for creating form in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a table in my database. I want to use the data of that table and create form of that data. I created a module and made a form.php page. Wrote select query in function but how to make form from that data?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you want to create listing page of the table data. Here is how you can create a tabular listing with pagination and column sorting.

Suppose you have a table named "students" with the below fields.
id, name, email

**1. Create a controller in your module in the below path.**
*modules/your_module/Src/Controller/StudentsController.php*

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\your_module\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
class StudentsController extends ControllerBase {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function list() {
        $header = array(
            array('data' => t('ID'), 'field' => 'st.id'),
            array('data' => t('Name'), 'field' => 'st.name'),
            array('data' => t('Email'), 'field' => 'st.email'),
        );
        $query = db_select('students', 'st')
        ->fields('st', array('id', 'name', 'email'))
        ->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')
        ->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')
        ->orderByHeader($header);
        $data = $query->execute();
        $rows = array();
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $rows[] = array('data' => (array) $row);
        }
        $build['table_pager'][] = array(
            '#type' => 'table',
            '#header' => $header,
            '#rows' => $rows,
        );
        $build['table_pager'][] = array(
            '#type' => 'pager',
        );
        return $build;
    }
}
```

So your controller action is ready, now you have to add routing in order to create path to this listing page.

**2. Create routing.yml file inside your module folder as the file name mentioned below, and the code below.**
*modules/your_module/your_module.routing.yml*

```
students.list:
  path: 'admin/config/students/list'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\your_module\Controller\StudentsController::list'
    _title: 'Students List'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access students list'
```

**3. To create permissions, you can create the followin ing file in your module.**
*modules/your_module/your_module.permissions.yml*

```
access students list:
  title: 'Access students list page'
```

- Clear CMS cache
- Go to People => Permissions, Enable the permission for relevant user roles.

Then, browse your page "*admin/config/students/list*"